# How to handle ASP.NET MVC3 Request Validation exceptions as model or property validation errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-validation, request-validation

My question is hopefully pretty straight forward.
Upon submitting my form, I would like to flag all properties (fields) that have invalid characters (specifically HTML) as model errors.
The issue I am facing is that Request Validation kicks in ***before*** model binding/validation and I get HTTP 500...
I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81991) that advertises either using `[AllowHtml]` property attribute on your Model/ViewModel or using  `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` in web.config, but what I am looking for is how to "***globally catch Request Validation exceptions and show them as model errors***". Furthermore, I don't want to "strip" HTML tags, I want to notify the user that their input is not valid.

I thought about using Regular Expression validation attributes to find bad input, but as I mentioned, the Request Validation on ASP.NET MVC3 occurs before model binding/validation, so that is a no-go...

A really [good overview of the Request Validation can be found here](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/19/understanding-request-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx).

Comment: Let me understand your problem. You want to flag your properties in code-behind and manipulate them in code-behind when there are any validation error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your only intention is to get the Request Validation exception during model binding and show the errors as model state error. Here is the sample,

```
    using System.Web.Helpers;
    public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            try
            {
                return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
            }
            catch(HttpRequestValidationException ex)
            {
                var modelState = new ModelState();
                modelState.Errors.Add(ex.Message);
                var key=bindingContext.ModelName;
                var value = controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Unvalidated().Form[key];
                modelState.Value = new ValueProviderResult(value, value,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                bindingContext.ModelState.Add(key, modelState);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new MyModelBinder();
    }
```

This will add the exception of **only** request validation in model state. Sorry, If I don't understand your question clearly.

Comment: @zam6ak, Add using System.Web.Helpers and see my updated answer. Note, this is just a quick answer and not very much optimized. Sorry for that.

Comment: This seems to work nicely - I am not sure why are you saying it is "not very much optimized" :)

Comment: @zam6ak, I said this because I have created this in a quick time. So, it may be not optimized or there may be some other better way.

Comment: For everyone's info, Unvalidated() is new on Request as of .NET 4.5

Comment: When using a custom DefaultBinder like in this example, is there any way of getting the display name of the field set in bindingContext.ModelName?

Comment: Works perfectly for me.  I wanted to return an error message to the user instead of an exception and this code accomplishes that.

Comment: Very nice. Note: `Unvalidated()` seems to be a property in MVC5. With `controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Unvalidated.Form[key]` it worked for me.